# Xcode Ios Configurable-C How To Compare CGPoint's

Tags: ios, xcode

How Do I Compare CGPoint's
I Tried This

```
if (imageView.center > invisibleimage.center) {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

well think about it, what makes a center bigger than another center? that doesnt make sense. what you probably want is

```
if (imageView.center.x > invisibleimage.center.x && 
    imageView.center.y > invisibleimage.center.y)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want compare equal,use this function.

```
CGPointEqualToPoint
```

Document

> Returns whether two points are equal.
>
> true if the two specified points
> are the same; otherwise, false.

If you want to compare greater or less,you have to define what is "Greater" like **Fonix** said

Answer (score 1):

CGCenter is a struct which comprises of

```
CGCenter {
float x,
float y.
}
```

Only comparable condition for CGCenter is that are two centers equal as in their x and y are equal, that is done by `CGPointEqualToPoint` or else you can compare their x and y as in

```
if(myLabel.center.x > myOtherLabel.center.x)
OR if(myLabel.center.y > myOtherLabel.center.y)
```

Hope this helps you